# How do I listen to multiple accounts using get_action_traces in dfuse

Tags: dfuse

According to this DEC 5th update:

"Added support to filter multiple accounts, receivers and action_names in the get_action_traces WS request.

- Please use that instead of doing multiple parallel get_action_traces"

How should I change the code below, if I want to listen to 5 different tokens' transfers? what do I write in the `account` section?

[image: get_action_traces]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `"account": "eosio.token"` to `"accounts": "tokenacct1|tokenaxct2|tokenacct3"`

See the docs for more details https://docs.dfuse.io